# Remove all objects matching a condition

Tags: c#

Given

```
        List<LabEntity> selected = originalSettings.SelectedInstanceLabs;
        List<LabEntity> available = Presenter.GetLabs(dateRange);
        if (!firstLoad)
        {
            //Remove selected labs from the available labs
            available.Remove(?);// Remove Where selected.Id = available.Id
        }
```

Is there an extension method that can complete the task for multiple items?  Remove only works on one at a time. The other Remove-type methods don't seem up to the task either.  I could stick a foreach on there, but there's gotto be a more concise implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like this? :

```
        List<LabEntity> selected = originalSettings.SelectedInstanceLabs;
        List<LabEntity> available = Presenter.GetLabs(dateRange);
        if (!firstLoad)
        {
            //Remove selected labs
            available = available.Except<LabEntity>(selected).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: I like the way this approach reads, though this approach assumes that `LabEntity` objects can be compared for equality correctly (which we don't currently know.) It will also remove any duplicates that might have existed in `available` prior to the call. If those criteria are met, though, then I like this approach.

Comment: Ah yes!  Except is SO much easier.

Answer (score 6):

Sure can!

`available.RemoveAll( ~delegate goes here~)`

Something like;
`available.RemoveAll(a => selected.Exists(s => s.Id == a.Id));`

Pardon my 4.0 delegate syntax, not sure what version your using...

**Edit:** Updated from comments (@vcsjones)

Comment: [`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.80).aspx) isn't 4.0. It's been there since 2.0.

Comment: @vcsjones I meant the delegate syntax, but I can see the confusion. I'll update the post.

Comment: Sorry, I need just a little more hand holding to get this to work.  I tried `available.RemoveAll((x, selected) => x.OrderId == selected.OrderId);` to no avail...

Comment: @AlG That's C# 3.0 then, not 4 :-).

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Give `available.RemoveAll(a => selected.Exists(s => s.Id == a.Id));` a shot.

Comment: @vcsjones DOH! This is what I get for going from .Net 2 to 4. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfy with LINQ, you can either filter them at the beginning:

```
var selectedSet = HashSet<LabEntry>(selected);
var available = Presenter.GetLabs(dateRange).Where(l => !selectedSet.Contains(l));
```

or you can filter post hoc:

```
available.RemoveAll(l => selectedSet.Contains(l));
```

Of the two, the first should be faster, as it avoids creating a collection merely to remove items from it.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines would do it:

`available.RemoveAll(x => selected.Contains(y => (y.Id == x.Id)));`